# ngOnChanges is calling up multiple times

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I have generated multiple ion-slides using ngFor, and inserted a component there. It is calling ngOnChanges multiple time. I want it should call only once, so that I can call my api.

I have tried using multiple angular lifecycle hooks.

This is how I created my slides, menu has 19 elements

```
<ion-slides #slides [options]="slideOpts" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged($event)">
<ion-slide *ngFor="let i of menu; let j = index">
  <h1>{{ i.name }}</h1>
  <app-homenews [categoryId]="currentCategoryId" ></app-homenews>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

This is how we are making change detection

```
@Input() categoryId: number;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   let chg = changes['categoryId'];
   console.log(chg.currentValue);
}
```

I want it to be called only once, it is calling 19 times now.

Can I use rxjs here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ngOnChanges` runs when there is change in value of Input variable comes from a template binding.So triggering it multiple times is a normal behavior.If you want to execute some code only once you can use it like this

```
@Input() isFirstRun;
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(this.isFirstRun){
     let chg = changes['categoryId'];
     console.log(chg.currentValue);
  }
}

<ion-slide *ngFor="let i of menu; let j = index">
  <h1>{{ i.name }}</h1>
  <app-homenews [isFirstRun]="j===0?true:false" [categoryId]="currentCategoryId" ></app-homenews>
</ion-slide>
```

Comment: I doubt any of the above are going to work as the component template is inside for loop, so it will call ngOnInit each time( same as it is calling ngOnChanges - even CurrentCategoryId is not modified inside loop)

the variable approach will also not work for same reason, that variable will get default value each time

Comment: So you can make `isFirstRun` as input variable and supply it from parent.and in template first iteration you can send value as true.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a isFirstRun flag in a service and use that in your component 
You can continue using ngOnchanges as it will be helpful in case the value changes

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
if (this.flagService.isFirstRun || value has changed) {
// call API
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method one times to avoid the use of ngOnChanges cycle.

In your component :

```
private _changes;
private id;
@Input()
  set changes(changes) {     

      this._changes= changes;
      this.id = changes[id];

    }
  }
  get changes(): string {
    return this._changes;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are technically correct, I feel it is better to use a getter-setter or the SimpleChanges object that you already passed to the lifecycle hook, rather than a isFirstRun flag. The SimpleChanges object contains all the information you already need.

```
class SimpleChange {
  constructor(previousValue: any, currentValue: any, firstChange: boolean)
  previousValue: any
  currentValue: any
  firstChange: boolean
  isFirstChange(): boolean
}
```

During runtime, an object containing one/many SimpleChanges objects corresponding to the component's Input variables will be passed into NgOnChanges, having the format above. it would be easier to check the firstChange value like I have done below;

```
@Input() categoryId: number;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if(changes['categoryId'].firstChange) {
     let chg = changes['categoryId'];
     console.log(chg.currentValue);
     //other program logic
   }
}
```

Please note: if you're inputting data from an API response into a child component, chances are before the API call is run a null value will be sent on initialisation, and firstChange will be set to true for that Input. In that particular case, checking the previous value as null and whether the current value is present should be enough.